# Drawing on HTML canvas from multiple files using JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, electron

So basically im working on a project using electron and canvas. I have a function that i call 60 times/second (using setInterval) and everytime that i want to draw some new thing i create a new file with the drawing methods and i have to call that function inside my main loop. There's any way to load all my "scripts" without calling each one, one by one, on my loop function manually? so i could just throw they on a specific folder and they would be loaded and all instructions inside a Draw fucntion would be called on my main loop? kinda like a scripting engine. I dont know if im using the wrong terms but i tried to look around and didnt found anything like that.

Comment: Do you want to load js files. If yes then load by using document.createElement("script") tags. It will load. Is this ?

Comment: not directly related to your question, but you really should not use setInterval for this, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: "i create a new file with the drawing methods" why is that necessary? I would manage only one file and pass drawing commands to it which would be processed in that only file. Like taking `drawAttribs, drawFcns`, then for each `canvas[attrib.name] = attrib.value` and `canvas.[fcn.name].apply(canvas, fcn.args)` (I'm not certain it could work though)